# Couldn't quite understand the loops used to create the pattern

Tags: python, for-loop

[image]

Can someone explain the loops used here?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Have you tried tinkering with the code yourself to figure out what's happening?

Comment: type your code into `https://pyfiddle.io/` and fiddle with what you do not  understand - maybe you can groke it then

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.
[You should not post code as an image because:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755) ... 
[Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: [`for` statements in the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) ... [Visualize Your Code](http://pythontutor.com/)

Comment: @wwii I'm sorry, noted. I'm actually new to SO.
Will definitely do so in the future. Thank you.

Comment: You should update your question - make it specific like your comment to @NielsHenkins answer. ..The [`print` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) normally terminates with a newline character - the *print* in the inner loop specified a space for the end character so all subsequent prints are on the same line - the *print* at the bottom of the outer loop *creates* a new line.

Comment: @wwii Thanks for the help. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in range(0, n):` will run the loop 5 time (`n` being 5), with `i` being 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4.

`for i in range(n, 0, -1):` will also run the loop 5 times, but now backwards (`-1` being the step argument, meaning 'minus 1' every step. So `i` wil be 5, 4, 3, 2 and 1.

The function is defined as `range([start], stop, [step])`. Start is the startnumber of the range (if not specified, it will be 0). Stop is the end of the range, but is not included itself. The 'step' is the size of the steps (default is 1). 
`range(2, 10, 2)` will for example give you 2, 4, 6 and 8.

Comment: I actually understand this part, but what I'm actually facing trouble with is the following:
• The usage of the 2nd loop where "J" was implemented.
• The [ print(" ") ] statement used at the end of the for loops
Thank u so much for ur help it is really appreciated and excuse me if my questions are dumb somehow, I'm new to programming.

Comment: As far as I can review the code right now (from mobile), the print(“ “) statement is just to add a blank line between the lines of “<->”’s.

Comment: Thanks, you've been very helpful.